# MySQL ERROR 1349 What I am missing?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, subquery

I am getting a MySQL `1349` error, but it appears as though the error is incorrect:

```
ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

Can I not have ANY subqueries when creating a view?

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW  `wordpress`.`ffi_be_v_book_details` AS (
  SELECT ffi_be_courses. * , COALESCE(  `Total` , 0 ) AS  `Total` 
  FROM  `ffi_be_courses` 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * , COUNT(  `Course` ) AS  `Total` 
    FROM ffi_be_courses
    RIGHT JOIN (
      SELECT  `Course` 
      FROM  `ffi_be_bookcourses` 
      LEFT JOIN  `ffi_be_sale` ON ffi_be_bookcourses.SaleID = ffi_be_sale.SaleID
      WHERE DATE_ADD( ffi_be_sale.Upload, INTERVAL( 
        SELECT  `BookExpireMonths` 
        FROM  `ffi_be_settings` ) MONTH ) > CURDATE( ) AND ffi_be_sale.Sold =  '0'
      GROUP BY ffi_be_bookcourses.SaleID
    ) AS  `q1` ON ffi_be_courses.Code = q1.Course
    GROUP BY q1.Course
  ) AS  `q2` ON ffi_be_courses.Code = q2.Code
  WHERE ffi_be_courses.Type =  'Arts'
  ORDER BY ffi_be_courses.Name ASC
)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi .. can you try making multiple views -- one for each subquery

Comment: @Fox I know I could create multiple views, but I didn't want to have an excess of views just to get the one view I was hoping to construct. Thanks, though.

Comment: The above answers are correct. MySQL 5.5 does not allow subqueries in the FROM clause. It is allowed now, however, in MySQL 5.7.7 and later.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the fact that views in MySQL do not allow subqueries in the `from` clause.  They are allowed in the `select` and `where` and `having` clauses, however.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-restrictions.html) is quite clear:

> Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

In your case, you can probably rewrite the `from` clause as a correlated subquery in the `select` clause.  You can also use multiple layers of views to do what you want.

EDIT:

A SELECT statement in SQL has the following clauses:  `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY` (according to the standard).  In addition, MySQL adds things like `LIMIT`, and `INTO OUTFILE`.  You can see this in the way that MySQL describes the `SELECT` clause in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).  You can also see this in the documentation for almost any database.

Operations such as `join` are part of the `FROM` clause (similarly `WITH ROLLUP` is part of the `GROUP BY` and `DESC` is part of the `ORDER BY`).  These may seem like arcane syntactic conventions, but it becomes important when there is a restriction like the one above.

Perhaps one reason for the confusion is an indentation style that goes like:

```
select . . .
from t1
inner join t2
     on . . .
```

Where the join statements line up under the `select`.  This is misleading.  I would write this as:

```
select 
from t1 join
     t2
     on . . .
```

Only the `select` clauses line up under the `select.`

Comment: Could you point out where specifically I have a sub-query in the from clause? I'm not doing `SELECT FROM (SELECT ...) query`

Comment: @spryno724 . . . You have `left join (select . . . `.

Comment: @spryno724 Your LEFT JOIN is using a subquery, you can't do that in a view

Comment: @spryno724 I'm guessing the joined derived table also counts

Comment: I misunderstood the documentation, I understood it to mean you couldn't generate a set of results like so `SELECT FROM (SELECT ...) query`. I didn't know it meant no subqueries after the `FROM` clause. Looks like this view is not possible in MySQL. :(

Comment: Right, the FROM clause includes all the table-references and JOIN clauses.  Basically everything up to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @OliverSpryn: Before *MySQL 5.7.7*, it wasn't possible. Search for "A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:" in the MySQL online documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) --

A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:

The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

Create a separate view for each of the FROM clause.