# Prevent Duplicates in mysql join in a view

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. One is items and one is ebay listings.
There can be mulitiple ebay listings for given item.

I have a view that aggregates (left joins) a bunch of pricing info from several tables including the ebay table.

`e.custom_label` will start with `i.id` but is not guaranteed to be an exact match.

```
SELECT i.id, i.price AS master_price, e.price AS ebay_price
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN ebay e ON ((e.custom_label LIKE CONVERT(concat(i.id,'%') using latin1)))
```

This is greatly simplified, but should describe the problem.

As expected, due to having multiple ebay listings that will match the ON statement, you will get something like

```
item   master_price    ebay_price
1234       29.95          29.95
1235       36.95          29.95
1235       36.95          29.95
```

Normally we would use a subquery in place of the `ebay` tabel in the join to filter out the duplicates, but since this is a view, we can't. This keeps us from doing a group by on the joined table.  Is there any other way to filter out the duplicates in a way that keeps the base table editable from a view?

For this view, it's more important to get a price (and know that product is listed on ebay) than to make sure all the ebay prices are the same, so I only need one line.  The UI relies on that there will only be one row per item.

Comment: Why can't you use a subquery in a view? Have you tried it? Long story short, have you tried `GROUP BY item`?

Comment: Yes. (i.e.:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983379/mysql-error-1349-what-i-am-missing)

Comment: Before you get too far down the path of creating views in MySQL, I recommend you make sure you understand the performance implications for large tables... predicates from the outer query don't get pushed down into the view query, and the result from the view query is always materialized as a derived table with no indexes. (The absence of indexes on derived tables is partially addressed in the latest releases of MySQL.)  **Danger, Will Robinson. Danger!**

Comment: a) Have you tried to `group by item` b) you CAN use a subquery in a view, but for all purposes - a subquery is exactly the same thing as a `JOIN` - therefore, whatever you can achieve with a subquery - you can do the same with a `JOIN`. c) you haven't specified MySQL version in use d) if those ebay prices are always the same for the same item, why would you store it multiple times in the table in the first place? Unique index and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does wonders (even `INSERT IGNORE` would help you).

Comment: @N.B. Adding a group by to the whole query does fix the issue, but breaks editing. Views with group by cannot be used to update the table.

Comment: So read from the view then, and update the underlying table? Or fix that table that contains duplicates for no reason, that's where your problems come from, I gave you a hint how to fix it for good.

Comment: @N.B. there's no doubt there is probably some normalization that could be done. The rows in the ebay table are ebay listings, with their own titles prices, etc, direct from ebay.  I never said the ebay prices for a product  would always be the same. I just said, for the purpose of this view, I care more that there is a price than what it is.  I understand your line of thinking and agree about the underlying problems, but your solutions aren't feasible at the moment.  Also, the framework I'm using will not allow viewing with the view and updating the table directly. It has to be the same table.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks, I was not aware of this.  This is an internal management tool used by two people on tables of less than 2000 rows. I'm not really too concerned with performance.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to hear that the tools you use aren't really useful to you if you have to come up with hackish ways of dealing with a database. I'll wish you a good luck, and sorry if I'm coming off as rude but I generally dislike solving problems by going against the design of something such as database. If your framework isn't helping you, then it might be an idea to deal with that problem first?

Comment: Your `LIKE CONCAT...` does not make sense -- `LIKE` returns true/false, which becomes `1`/`0` for comparing against `i.id`.

Comment: Fixed. I didn't simplify properly..

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list, since you are only pulling one column. (I'll repeat the admonition in my comment on the question... **Danger, Will Robinson, Danger!**)

I'm not getting my brain wrapped around the join predicate, what that is supposed to be doing...

```
i.id = ((e.custom_label LIKE CONVERT(concat(i.id,'%') using latin1)))
```

The **`e.custom_label LIKE foo`** is going to return a boolean. A value of TRUE, FALSE or NULL. Evaluated in a numeric context, the boolean is going to be a 1, 0 or NULL. Then taking that result, and doing an equality comparison to the `id` column... I'm not getting it, how that whole expression is going to evaluate to TRUE for any id value other than 1 or 0.

But then again, the whole business of matching on the first part of `custom_label` just seems rather bizarre to me.

Which rows from ebay are supposed to match which item.id values, given something like this:

```
 item.id
 -------
      12
     123

 ebay.custom_label
 -----------------
 122
 123
 1234
 12345
```

But that whole business aside...

I'm not sure why a correlated subquery in the SELECT list wouldn't work for you. As an example.  (Use whatever "match condition" you need in the WHERE clause of the correlated subquery.)

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.price AS master_price
     , ( SELECT e.price
           FROM ebay e
          WHERE e.custom_label REGEXP CONCAT('^',i.id)
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS ebay_price
  FROM items i
```

There may be some restriction in a stored view definitions. (Not much experience with stored view definitions. We just avoid creating stored view definitions due to the kinds of problems that can be introduced. And those problems are likely going to be much larger than the problem the stored view definition was a solution to.)

Comment: whoops, the actual join is `LEFT JOIN cffhub_channel_ebay e on((e.custom_label like convert(concat(p.posid,'%') using latin1)))`  ... I managed to mess it up when simplifying.  Thank you for this answer, I will try it out.