# MySQL 5.6 Select Statement

Tags: mysql, view

For some reason I cant seem to figure this out even though I know the answer is probably staring me in the face.

I have a two tables, `DEVICES` and `DEVICE_OWNER`.

The relationship here is a one to many.

`DEVICES` columns are `pk_device_id`, `DEVICE_OWNER` columns are `fk_device_id, assigned_date, and fk_staff_id`.

I am trying to create a view that will show ALL devices along with the last `fk_staff_ID` based on assigned_date. I wrote this view based on other answers on this website which shows exactly what I want but MySQL will not let me save this as a view, can anyone offer any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    deow.fk_staff_id,
devices.*
FROM
    devices_owner deow
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        fk_device_id,
        MAX(assigned_date) AS MaxDateTime,
        fk_staff_id
    FROM
        devices_owner
    GROUP BY
        FK_DEVICE_ID
) groupeddeow ON deow.FK_DEVICE_ID = groupeddeow.fk_device_id
AND deow.ASSIGNED_DATE = groupeddeow.MaxDateTime
RIGHT JOIN devices ON devices.PK_DEVICE_ID = deow.FK_DEVICE_ID
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, can you post the error message?

Comment: Please include the full query you tryed with also the CREATE VIEW statement not only the SELECT query...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using Navicat to build the query so I dont have the create view statement. The error I am getting is "1349 - Views SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Comment: A simple web search for that error turns up the fact that MySQL apparently does not support subqueries assuming nothing has changed in the last 4 years on that front. Here was the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983379/mysql-error-1349-what-i-am-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version should work without a subquery in the FROM clause

```
SELECT `do`.fk_staff_id
FROM devices AS `d`
LEFT JOIN devices_owner AS `do` ON `d`.pk_device_id = `do`.fk_device_id
WHERE `do`.fk_device_id IS NULL
  OR (`do`.fk_device_id,  `do`.assigned_date) 
     IN (SELECT fk_device_id, MAX(assigned_date)
         FROM devices_owner
         GROUP BY fk_device_id
        )
;
```

The `OR` may (probably will) hurt performance, so you may want to UNION two versions of the query (one with each condition)... assuming VIEWs don't have limitations on those as well.

---

Edit: To elaborate on this condition...

```
(`do`.fk_device_id,  `do`.assigned_date) 
   IN (SELECT fk_device_id, MAX(assigned_date)
       FROM devices_owner
       GROUP BY fk_device_id
      )
```

This evaluates to true when the resultset from the subquery contains a result row that matches the exactly to the values in candidate result row of the outer query.

It is a variation on this kind of logic (examples progressing from simplest to more complex):

- 1 IN (1, 2, 3) => true, 4 IN (1, 2, 3) => false
- (1,2) IN ((1,1),(1,2),(1,3)) => true, (2,1) IN ((1,1),(1,2),(1,3)) => false
- 1 IN ((1,1),(1,2),(1,3)) => probably error (at best false)

The condition being elaborated basically just replaces the value list on the right of these examples with a subquery that will be treated as such a list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that statements works well. The last part that begins with the OR, is it looking for items that have either, fk_device_id and assigned_date in the second select statement? I would have never been able to come up with something like this. Also, would it be better (performance wise) to just create a field for LAST_STAFF_ID in the devices table and have a trigger update it every time there is an insert or update on devices_owner table?